# Get the Newest File in a Google Drive Folder

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sheets, deprecated

I have the following lines in my Google App script, but the File API is now deprecated and I am unable to update the code.

The original lines are:

```
var folder = DocsList.getFolder('Folder Name');
var file = folder.getFilesByType(DocsList.FileType.SPREADSHEET)[0];
var filename = file.getName(); //and get its name
var fileId = file.getId(); // its ID
var fileurl = file.getUrl(); //and its url
var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileId);`
```

I need my script to go to a folder on my drive, get the LATEST google spreadsheet file in this folder and open it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the code that will get the newest file in the folder:

```
function getNewestFileInFolder() {
  var arryFileDates,file,fileDate,files,folder,folders,
      newestDate,newestFileID,objFilesByDate;

  folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('yourFolderName');  
  arryFileDates = [];
  objFilesByDate = {};
  
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    folder = folders.next();
    
    files = folder.getFilesByType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");//Change file type as needed
    fileDate = "";//Initialize variable to empty string
    
    while (files.hasNext()) {//If no files are found then this won't loop
      file = files.next();
      //Uncomment log statements for debugging
      //Logger.log('xxxx: file data: ' + file.getLastUpdated());
      //Logger.log('xxxx: file name: ' + file.getName());
      //Logger.log('xxxx: mime type: ' + file.getMimeType())
      //Logger.log(" ");
      
      fileDate = file.getLastUpdated();
      objFilesByDate[fileDate] = file.getId(); //Create an object of file names by file ID
      
      arryFileDates.push(file.getLastUpdated());
    }

    if (arryFileDates.length === 0) {//The length is zero so there is nothing
      //to do
      return;
    }

    arryFileDates.sort(function(a,b){return b-a});
   
    //Logger.log(arryFileDates);
    
    newestDate = arryFileDates[0];
    //Logger.log('Newest date is: ' + newestDate);
    
    newestFileID = objFilesByDate[newestDate];
    
    //Logger.log('newestFile: ' + newestFileID);
    //return newestFile;
    
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(newestFileID);
    //Logger.log('file name that is now open: ' + ss.getName());
  };
};
```

Comment: What happens when there is not a file in the folder? I was thinking about using this on a trigger to check weekly.

Comment: In the example, the code searches for spreadsheet files.  If no Google Sheets file was found, then the `hasNext()` method would be false, and the `arryFileDates` would have a length of zero, because it's instantiated as an empty array.  See updated code for testing for zero length and halting the code if no files are found.  You could also add a value to the array, that stated: "Nothing Found"  `arryFileDates.push("no file found")`

Answer (score 1):

No worries about that, you can use `DriveApp` instead. Refer to this page for all the possible methods you can use on Drive files:  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app

Hope that helps!