# Trigger an appscript to copy new data to a set location

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, eventtrigger

I have a folder that is constantly being upload with a new google sheet on fridays.
I was wondering if there is a way to trigger a script to copy the name and the data of the new sheet in this forlder and place it in another location into a master sheet.

The name of the sheet is constantly been updated with the date of when it was upload.
the master sheets name and location will never change.

```
function runsies() {
 
  copyRange(
    "the google sheet ID", // google ID of the master sheet
    "the name of the sheet!A2:H", //name of the master sheet!, rnag to copy from mastersheet
    "getNewestFileInFolder", //Destination
    "detination!A2" // name of the Dump sheet! and the location of the dump file. 
  );
 
}

function copyRange(sourceRange, destinationID, destinationRangeStart) {

  const sourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(getNewestFileInFolder());
  const sourceRng = sourceSS.getRange(sourceRange)
  const sourceVals = sourceRng.getValues();

  const destinationSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationID);
  const destStartRange = destinationSS.getRange(destinationRangeStart);
  const destSheet = destStartRange.getSheet();

  const destRange = destSheet.getRange(
    destStartRange.getRow(),
    destStartRange.getColumn(),
    sourceVals.length,
    sourceVals[0].length
  );

  destRange.setValues(sourceVals);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
};
```

Comment: In your situation, how is run `I have a folder that is constantly being upload with a new google sheet on fridays.`? For example, if this is run by a Google Apps Script, how about adding a script for achieving your goal to the current script? If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. To further explain, when using import range for this trigger. The last Id is then copied and placed into the master sheet. But I need to figure out a way to have the script look for the newly created sheet and copy that data.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. About `this trigger`, what is `this trigger` in the case of your question?

Comment: How is the new Google Sheet being created? Is it using a script with time trigger? If so, can you share the script you have?

Comment: Yes please share the code you are using.

Comment: the problem im facing is, the source id changes when the new google sheet is created. So I am unable to capture the new sheet.

Comment: The script you shared, this is used to get the values from the source and set it to the destination. How about for the google sheet being created? How is it being created? Please also share the script for that or is it manually being created?

Comment: You are correct. That sheet is being created manually.

Comment: I'm assuming the created sheets are in the folder so the latest file in the folder must be the newly created sheet correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try:**

```
function getNewestFileInFolder() {
  var arryFileDates, file, fileDate, files, folder, folders,
    newestDate, newestFileID, objFilesByDate;

  folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('yourFolderName');
  arryFileDates = [];
  objFilesByDate = {};

  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    folder = folders.next();

    files = folder.getFilesByType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");
    fileDate = "";

    while (files.hasNext()) {//If no files are found then this won't loop
      file = files.next();

      fileDate = file.getLastUpdated();
      objFilesByDate[fileDate] = file.getId(); //Create an object of file names by file ID

      arryFileDates.push(file.getLastUpdated());
    }

    if (arryFileDates.length === 0) {//The length is zero so there is nothing
      //to do
      return;
    }

    arryFileDates.sort(function (a, b) { return b - a });

    newestDate = arryFileDates[0];

    newestFileID = objFilesByDate[newestDate];

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(newestFileID);
  };
  return newestFileID;
};
```

How about using this function to return the ID of the latest spreadsheet file in the Drive Folder. Then use this as an input for your importRange() function:

```
function copyRange(sourceRange, destinationID, destinationRangeStart) {

  const sourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(getNewestFileInFolder());
  const sourceRng = sourceSS.getRange(sourceRange)
  const sourceVals = sourceRng.getValues();

  const destinationSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationID);
  const destStartRange = destinationSS.getRange(destinationRangeStart);
  const destSheet = destStartRange.getSheet();

  const destRange = destSheet.getRange(
    destStartRange.getRow(),
    destStartRange.getColumn(),
    sourceVals.length,
    sourceVals[0].length
  );

  destRange.setValues(sourceVals);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
};
```

I advise you change the function name for your `importRange()` since there is a built in [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en#:%7E:text=IMPORTRANGE%20automatically%20checks%20for%20updates,trigger%20a%20reload%20on%20IMPORTRANGE%20.) function in google sheet just to avoid any possible conflicts and confusion

**Update:**
Updated code upon discussion in comments to avoid confusion.

```
function copyRange() {
  const sourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SourceSpreadsheetID");
  const sourceRng = sourceSS.getRange("A1:A");
  const sourceVals = sourceRng.getValues();
  // console.log(sourceVals);

  const destinationSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(getNewestFileInFolder());
  const destStartRange = destinationSS.getRange("A1:A");
  const destSheet = destStartRange.getSheet();

  const destRange = destSheet.getRange(
    destStartRange.getRow(),
    destStartRange.getColumn(),
    sourceVals.length,
    sourceVals[0].length
  );

  destRange.setValues(sourceVals);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
};
```

References:

- [Get Newest File in a Google Drive Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323703/get-the-newest-file-in-a-google-drive-folder)
- [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en#:%7E:text=IMPORTRANGE%20automatically%20checks%20for%20updates,trigger%20a%20reload%20on%20IMPORTRANGE%20.)

Comment: how do i then link the newFileID to the copyRange?

Comment: @JohnnyQuest In the answer I posted on the function copyRange, line const sourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(getNewestFileInFolder()); . This uses the function getNewestFileInFolder which returns the newestFileID to be used as the sourceSS.

Comment: sorry for waisting your time, just keep getting an error:   Exception: Invalid argument: range

Comment: I am not sure why, it is working on my end. Can you try logging the getNewstFileInfolder() if it is returning the latest ID. @JohnnyQuest

Comment: I posted the code above again, could youtake a look at it to see if I have made amistake please and thank you.

Comment: In your copyRange(), no need to include the newestFileInFolder as an input, just replace const destinationSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationID) to -> const destinationSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(getNewestFileInFolder());. Change back the sourceSS as I thought it is where you will use the newestID. @JohnnyQuest

Comment: I have updated the posted answer to include the updated copyRange() function. I have tested it and it works. Of course you still have to edit the range accordingly. Also upon testing the getNewestFileInFolder(), this gets the latest file in the folder stated according to the last modified file. So if you created a new file but then edit an older file, it will get the ID of the older file as the newest ID. @JohnnyQuest